# Running WinForms with DevExpress components on Linux

Tags: linux, winforms, mono, devexpress, wine

Previously, our team developed applications using WinForms with DevExpress components. Now, we need to migrate these applications to Linux (Debian) but we are facing issues while trying to run them temporarily on Linux using wine or mono. The programs crash with errors related to DevExpress components. Is there any other way to launch WinForms programs with DevExpress components on linux? Or can anyone provide hints to launch them with mono or wine? We were hoping to use this temporary solution while slowly rewriting the applications on Avalonia.

Comment: DevExpress never claimed their libraries to be Mono compatible, so you shouldn't put any hope there.